# How to Read string from file and compare to each line of second file

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I'm making the post OS installation script that will include the Hardening section . And in this hardening section it will read the Kernel parameters from file A and compare to file /etc/sysctl.conf and if parameters are not available in sysctl.conf then it will add it in sysctl.conf .

Parameters in custom file

```
################## Hardening ############################

kernel.exec-shield = 1
kernel.randomize_va_space = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.log_martians = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0

##########################################################
```

Now i added these lines for Hardening.

```
for i in $(cat /etc/sysctl.conf)
do
        if ! grep -Fxq " $i " /etc/sysctl.conf
        then
        echo -e "$i" > ~/testfile
        fi
done
```

Problem with this one this script is that it treats each space in kernel parameters as a space line and the problem starts right from the beginning in "for i in $(cat /etc/sysctl.conf)"

And this is the debug info

```
./LinuxHardening.sh
++ date
+ LOGDATE='Mon Feb  9 07:58:07 EST 2015'
+ echo Mon Feb 9 07:58:07 EST 2015
+ tee HardeningLog
Mon Feb 9 07:58:07 EST 2015
+ echo -e '\n############ Kernel Hardening ############'
+ tee -a HardeningLog

############ Kernel Hardening ############
++ cat kernelparms
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq '##################' /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e '##################'
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq Hardening /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e Hardening
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq '############################' /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e '############################'
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq kernel.exec-shield /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e kernel.exec-shield
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq = /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e =
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq 1 /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e 1
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq kernel.randomize_va_space /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e kernel.randomize_va_space
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq = /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e =
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq 1 /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e 1
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq = /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e =
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq 1 /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e 1
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq = /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e =
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq 1 /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e 1
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq = /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e =
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq 1 /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e 1
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq = /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e =
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq 1 /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e 1
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq = /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e =
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq 0 /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e 0
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq = /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e =
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq 1 /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e 1
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq = /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e =
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq 0 /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e 0
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq = /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e =
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq 0 /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e 0
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq net.ipv4.conf.default.log_martians /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e net.ipv4.conf.default.log_martians
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq = /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e =
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq 1 /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e 1
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq = /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e =
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq 0 /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e 0
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq = /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e =
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq 0 /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e 0
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq = /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e =
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq 0 /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e 0
+ for i in '$(cat kernelparms)'
+ grep -Fxq '##########################################################' /etc/sysctl.conf
+ echo -e '##########################################################'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not read line by line using while :

```
while read -r line
do
        if ! grep -Fxq " $line " /etc/sysctl.conf
        then
        echo -e "$line" >> ~/testfile
        fi
done </etc/sysctl.conf
```

and Replaced > with >>.

Comment: Excellent it worked . I used exact same method but i forgot to add "</etc/sysctl.conf " after done statement ... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```sh
while read i
do
        if ! grep -Fxq " $i " /etc/sysctl.conf
        then
        echo -e "$i" >> ~/testfile
        fi
done<kernelparms
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` and associative [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Example.html#Array-Example):

```
awk '!/^($|#)/{arr[$1]=$0}END{for(param in arr) print arr[param]}' /etc/sysctl.conf custom.conf
```

if order matters:

```
awk '!/^($|#)/{
  arr[$1] = $0
}
END {
  for(key in arr)
    print arr[key]
}' /etc/sysctl.conf custom.conf | sort > hardened.conf
```

`!/^($|#)/` - ignore commented or empty lines
`{arr[$1]=$0}` - store each line into arr, associating it to the kernel param; the line is updated everytime it sees the same param (i.e. from `custom.conf` as that is the last file to be read)
`END{for(param in arr) print arr[param]}` - after all the input has been read, print the associated line for each kernel parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct your problem is the expansion of the $( cat ) expression which is split at spaces so that the loop iterates over all fields in the data instead of the lines. To fix that you can use this approach...

```
while IFS= read -r i
do
  ...your loop code operating on $i here...

done < /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `IFS=$'\n'` and it wont treat spaces as new lines.

Comment: You do not read the OP question. Here the case is opposite! It's need to read entire lines, not word by word!

Comment: Which is what he achieves with my answer.

Comment: It will still glob by default without `set -f`.